# How to decrease cyclomatic complexity of the multiple conditions in if?

Tags: java, enums, cyclomatic-complexity, chain-of-responsibility

I have been trying to learn how to reduce cyclomatic complexity.
I have here 5 or more  conditional checks inside a if statement e.g

```
if(something1() && something2() && something3() && something4() && something5()){
     doThatThing();
}else{
     doThisThing();
}
```

The cyclomatic complexity of the above snippet is 6 (5 condition +1 if).
I know use of *Enum* and *Chain of Responsibilty* which is used to refactor multiple *if else*.
But, here I have only 1 *if else* where conditions can be many.

How to refactor the above code to reduce cyclomatic complexity since in real scenario I may have a maximum of 7 conditions.

Comment: I think that code is clear. One thing I might change is to name whatever condition is implied by all the somethings being true by moving them into a function, e.g. boolean rocketIsReady() { return fuelLoaded() && astronautsOnBoard() && ...; }

Comment: How much of the _related_ code are you allowed to change?

Comment: Thank you @tgdavies for your feedback.i shall keep your point in mind. But does that mean in case I assume 10 condition or more ,then if with 10 conditional is acceptable??

Comment: I have the liberty to build from scratch.

Comment: _",then if with 10 conditional is acceptable??"_ - depends. Let's say all of the condition functions return one aspect of the same object and having no parameters, they seem to solely depend on that object's state _and_ that `if` is called very often (much more often than the state changes) then it may be reasonable to condense those into a single property `canBeSchmoddelded`, which is calculated on statechange in the object on each of the individual properties. Then the `if` boils down to `if (o.canBeSchmoddeled()) {/*yadda*/} else {/*yodda*/}`.

Comment: Ok @fildor ,I got your point.I was of the opinion that conditions in if must be restricted to max 3 or 4 for better coding standards in any scenario

Comment: Well, the less the better. But if you are forced to do it, all "good practices" in the world won't help. Also, you need to take into account another aspect of software engineering: economy. Is it worth it, that you spend 10 hours just to make a metric happy if the code is actually not _that_ hard to read and works as expected and doesn't cause performance issues?

Comment: @fildor your point absolutely makes sense !!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Clean Code](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Martin-Clean-Code-A-Handbook-of-Agile-Software-Craftsmanship/PGM63937.html) by Robert C. Martin, page 301 it's a general smell:

> **G28: Encapsulate Conditionals**.
> Boolean logic is hard enough to understand without having to see it in the context of an `if` or `while` statement. Extract functions that explain the intent of the conditional.
> For example:
>
> `if (shouldBeDeleted(timer))`
>
> is preferable to
>
> `if (timer.hasExpired() && !timer.isRecurrent())`

Like @tgdavies is suggesting extract a function:

```java
if(shouldDoThatThing()) {
  doThatThing();
} else {
  doThisThing();
}

private boolean shouldDoThatThing() {
  return something1() && something2() && something3() && something4() && something5();
}
```